# How to POST an audio blob to a server javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, post, audio, blob

I'm trying to use JS and HTML send an audio blob file, made from a recording of the client's mic, to a server where I can save it. I've tried using FormData so I can associate the file with a name, based on a variable I have called ID.

I'm trying to use a php script to POST the FormData to a location on my server, but it's leaving me with a file with no name and no data (0 bytes).

My javascript includes the following function when the media recorder is stopped:

```
 mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
        audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {type:'audio/ogg'});
        blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('audio',audioBlob);
        formData.append('name',String(ID,".ogg"))
         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'audiosaver.php',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "multipart/form-data",
        processData: false,

    })
```

and the php:

```
 <?php
$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$name = "data/".$post_data;
$data = var_dump($_FILES);

file_put_contents($name, $data);
?>
```

I am get a file called "-.ogg" on my server in the data folder and it is 0 bytes. My XHR response payload says  array(0) {} and the XHR request payload params include:

```
 -----------------------------3054348293122

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="blob"

Content-Type: audio/ogg
```

and then a bunch of data that I'd assume is the audio encoded in text form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only figured it out through trial and error so it might not be the most optimised way to do it. But from what I got, if you send files or blobs through the POST method, then it goes to the `$_FILES` variable, and if you send anything else then it goes to the `$_REQUEST` method.

So the code that worked for me in Chrome, which I believe defaults to saving as .WAV, is (between php tags):

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name']);    

$fp = fopen("saved_audio/" . $_REQUEST["name"] . '.wav', 'wb');

fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```